# NUnit - Method are not included c#

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a UnitTest Method:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        Assert.True(false);
    }
```

When I tried to run it with the Test Explorer, I cant find it even if I build, rebuild, clean the solution

[image]

I dont know if I'm missing something, could you please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need install NUnit 2 o 3 Test Adapter extension on Visual Studio

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnit3TestAdapter